# How should I import styles for bootstrap theme (SASS)?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I am implementing an application using Kendo for Angular2 and has an issue. I don't understand how to add SASS(*.scss) styles correctly so controls looks bad (e.g. dropdowns have strange borders and opens without animation).

Did someone has such issue?

P.S. I tried to import styles in different order, tried to import _variables and _bootstrap-map.

Also I had an error when added reference to `'~@telerik/kendo-theme-bootstrap/src/packages/all'` - looks like references in this file are broken.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this approach?

http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/getting-started/#adding-the-styles-1

What is the actual error that you get?

Comment: I saw that but it describes how to use default theme and it works good.

Error is too big but main information is that paths to some files are broken.
Part of error:
` File to import not found or unreadable: ../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables`
(yes I have bootstrap installed :) )

Actually it looks strange that all paths rely on some modules outside of package.

Comment: Thank you. But actually I am adding styles the same way as in example and some components looks good. But like dropdownlist or file upload looks strange (dropdownlist has strange border, file upload has no file icons)